# Rephrase: Prove for any rational root of a polynomial ... that the numerator $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and the denominator $q$ is a factor of $a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, translation-request

> Prove for any rational root of a polynomial with integer coefficients,
>   $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0 \space\space\space\space (a_n \neq 0)$$
>   if written in lowest terms as $p/q$, that the numerator $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and the denominator $q$ is a factor of $a_n$. (This criterion permits us to obtain all rational real roots and hence to demonstrate the irrationality of any other real roots.)

I'm not precisely sure what this exercise is requesting. Can someone rephrase this for me?

$^\text{If using the `translation-request` tag is inappropriate, feel free to change it. I'm not aware of other tags regarding rephrasing an exercise.}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: *What* precisely "is not clear what the exercise is requesting"? Do you not understand some of the terminology, or the implication in the final sentence, or something else?

Comment: @BillDubuque -- Mostly just the first sentence. I'm not too concerned about the parenthesized part.

Comment: @SirJony Still not clear from my answer?

Comment: @Qwerty -- See upcoming comment under your answer.

Comment: A fraction $\,p/q\,$ representing a rational is in lowest terms if the denominator $\,q\,$ is minimal or, equivalently $\,\gcd(p,q) = 1,\ $ This hypothesis is necesssary else e.g. $\,x = 2/6\,$ is a root of $\, 3x-1\,$ but $\,6\nmid 3\,$ nor $\,2\nmid 1.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any rational root of the polynomial of the form ${p\over q}$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$, p is a factor of $a_0$ and $q$ is a factor of $a_n$.

Comment: By rational roots, do you mean $(x-\frac{p}{q})$?

Comment: @SirJony What else can a rational root look like? $(q\neq 0)$

Comment: @SirJony A rational root is a root that is a rational number.

Comment: So, by the end of the proof, should I end up with something like this: $x=\frac{p}{q}=\frac{ma_0}{na_n}$?

Comment: @SirJony No, since that does not imply that $\ p\mid a_0\ $ or $\ q\mid a_n\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque -- What are those |'s?

Comment: @SirJony $\ a\mid b\ $ means $a$ divides $b\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque -- Then why is my statement different?

Comment: @SirJony Your statement will be correct only if $n$ divides $a_0$ **and** $m$ divides $a_n$

Comment: @SirJony e.g. $\ \dfrac{6}{35} = \dfrac{2\cdot 3}{5\cdot 7}\ $ does not imply $\,6\mid 3\,$ and $\,35\mid 7.\ $ P.S "or" should be "and" in my 2nd last comment. Maybe you are mixing up the order of the divisibility relation. $a$ divides $n$ means $a$ is a factor or $n$, i.e. $n = ab\,$ for some integer $b\ $

Comment: Qwerty & @BillDubuque -- Thanks, I understand now. I'll mark your answer as green, but will delete this question later as it was more of a personal question of understanding (and won't be useful to anyone else).

Comment: @SirJony #HappyToHelp